# How Do I Filter This Chat Log?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following JSON file "messages.json:"

```
[{"participants": ["a", "b"], 
"conversation": [{"sender": "b", 
"created_at": "2019-08-15T19:34:24.551116+00:00",
"text": "Not so much..."},
{"sender": "a",
"created_at": "2019-08-15T19:34:14.562795+00:00",
"text": "Good! How was yours?"},
{"sender": "b",
"created_at": "2019-08-15T19:33:47.386847+00:00",
"text": "How was your day?"}]},
{"participants": ["c", "b"],
"conversation": [{"sender": "c", "created_at": "2019-08-15T19:33:22.069005+00:00",
"text": "Hi!"},
{"sender": "b",
"created_at": "2019-08-15T19:33:05.571631+00:00", "text": "Hello"}]}]
```

This is the "chatlog" from person C. How could I use JavaScript to filter out only the messages he/she **recieved** from person **c** and print them in the html body? I have jQuery included in the page.

I made some attempts myself but I can't seem to get it to work.

**EDIT 1:** Got my hands on my laptop, here's what I've got.

```
var a=$(json).filter(function (i,n){return 
n.participants==="c","b"});
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    alert(a[i].text[1]);
}
```

I have, clearly, a few issues I don't know how to resolve. First of all, I don't know how to filter on only messages **recieved** from **c** and I don't know how to display all of them in the body of the HTML. If anyone could help me out that would be great.

Comment: Yes, please share what you have tried already.

Comment: So my approach was to map each conversation to a list of messages from "c", then flatten the resulting nested arrays: `data.map(chat => chat.conversation.filter(message => message.sender == "c")).flat()`. This is only a partial answer, I mostly wanted to see if the first approach I thought of would work.
You can loop through that array and add the `text` from each item to a list or whatever in the body.

Comment: I do not know what language this comes from `function (i,n){return 
n.participants==="c","b"}` but it does not work in javascript. I've never seen jquery used on a blob of json either, but your filter function would look more like `i => i.participants.includes("c")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let data = messages_json;
let result = data.map(value=>value.conversation.filter(item=>item.sender=="c"));
```

You can also use `jquery` to change the innerText like so

```
<p id="msg"></p>
<script>$("#msg").text(result)</script>
```